# Hide emoji from keyboard in webview form

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

I am using a WebView that shows a form.
When I click on an input field, the android system shows me a softKeyboard.

Than, how can I show a pure text keyboard ?
Because now, in keyboard I can see emoji button, and I want to hide it.

Using a custom WebView I can override `onCreateInputConnection` but I can only set the type but cannot hide emoji.

Comment: There is no method for hide emoji in keyboard but you can enable/disable pro grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the good solution. But, It will be useful until you find the best solution.

> add the below attribute to xml

```
android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm 1234567890 QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
```

> Example

```
<EditText
            android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm 1234567890 QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your custom WebView and override the `onCreateInputConnection` like this:

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        InputConnection connection = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
        outAttrs.inputType =InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD;
        return connection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the answer from Nostradamus, I was able to find a helpful guide to create my own custom WebView class and override the `onCreateInputConnection`.

https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/managing-keyboard-on-webview-d2e89109d106